# How to count users with where condition previous row

Tags: mysql

please help me i have no idea for this... 
I have table like this (create_at YYYY-MM-DD). ID is auto increment

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|      ID      |    id_user  |    activity    |     create_at   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       1      |       10    |        A       |   2017-10-11    |
|       2      |       52    |        A       |   2017-10-11    |
|       3      |       41    |        A       |   2017-10-12    |
|       4      |       52    |        A       |   2017-10-12    |
|       5      |       41    |        B       |   2017-10-12    |
|       6      |       52    |        B       |   2017-10-13    |
|       7      |       10    |        B       |   2017-10-14    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to get count (mysql) user who doing activity "B" after activity "A" in sameday create_at.. In this case, the result is 1 (IDUser 41).. How can i do this in mysql? thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use a semi-join or a correlated subquery.

we start like this, users that are doing activity B

```
SELECT t.id_user
  FROM table_like_this t
 WHERE t.activity = 'B'
```

we can match those rows to users that are doing activity A on the "same day" with JOIN operation back to the same table...

```
SELECT t.id_user
  FROM table_like_this t
  JOIN table_like_this r
    ON r.id_user   = t.id_user
   AND r.create_at = t.create_at 
   AND r.activity  = 'A'
 WHERE t.activity = 'B'
```

As far as whether activity B is occurring "after" activity A, I don't see any information in the table that can tell us that (we can't tell what time each activity A and B occurred, and can't determine which one was "after" the other.)

For testing, we can include other columns in the SELECT list, to verify which rows from `t` and `r` are being returned, if the matching is being done properly.

Once we are satisfied, we can replace the SELECT list, to get a count of distinct id_user

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.id_user)
  FROM ...
```

Note that this will collapse occurrences of id_user that performed activity A and B on several different days so that the id_user will be counted only once.

If we want to count the number of days for each id_user, and include each of those days in the count, the query would need to be changed.